# Does adding two files in this way?

Tags: java

iam adding two files in this way but i got error message which is not add two files in this way.
File employ = new File("E:/employee.xml","E:/one/two/student.xml");

Comment: what do you mean you're ADDING two files? They're not "Numbers" that can be added!

Comment: adding means i am calling two files .how can call two files in one statement.

Comment: they're not functions/methods that can be called!

Comment: You will need to make two objects, one for each file

Comment: So the real question is WHY do want to open two files as if they where one? If you just want to read both files then open and process them sequentially (i.e. one after the other).

Comment: precisely what I mean @corlettk (+1)

Comment: Language barriers can be extremely frustrating... Through experience I've found paraphrasing the question (and asking for confirmation of my understanding) tends to best (sometimes the only) way forward to help folks get to where they need to be.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor you used is mentioned in Java API docs as:

> **public File(String parent,String child)**
>
> Creates a new `File` instance from a parent pathname string and a child
>   pathname string.
>
> If parent is null then the new File instance is created as if by
>   invoking the single-argument File constructor on the given child
>   pathname string.
>
> Otherwise the parent pathname string is taken to denote a directory,
>   and    the child pathname string is taken to denote either a directory
>   or a file. If the child pathname string is absolute then it is
>   converted into a relative pathname in a system-dependent way. If
>   parent is the empty string then the new File instance is created by
>   converting child into an abstract pathname and resolving the result
>   against a system-dependent default directory. Otherwise each pathname
>   string is converted into an abstract pathname and the child abstract
>   pathname is resolved against the parent.
>
> **Parameters**:   `parent` - The parent pathname string   `child` - The child
>   pathname string
>
> **Throws**: `NullPointerException` - If child is `null`

It is not for the purpose ofadding two files. You need to do some work yourself write some logic for adding the two files.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to merge two XML files together into an XML file. You should look into `Apache Commons Configurations` if you want the merged file to make business sense.

```
CombinedConfiguration
```

http://commons.apache.org/configuration/userguide/howto_combinedconfiguration.html

Comment: he wants to call two files! I don't understand what that means though

Answer (score 0):

```
File employ = new File("E:\\employee.xml");
File employ2 = new File("E:\\one\\two\\student.xml");
```

??

Answer (score 0):

If by "adding two files" you mean that you want to concatenate two files, try this:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.io.FileInputStream;  

public class CopyFile{  
    private static void copyfile(String srFile, String dtFile){  
        try{  
            File f1 = new File(srFile);  
            File f2 = new File(dtFile);  
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(f1);  

            //For Append the file.  
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(f2,true);  

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];  
            int len;  
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0){  
                out.write(buf, 0, len);  
            }  
            in.close();  
            out.close();  
            System.out.println("File copied.");  
        }  
        catch(FileNotFoundException ex){  
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage() + " in the specified directory.");  
            System.exit(0);  
        }  
        catch(IOException e){  
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());           
        }  
    }  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        switch(args.length){  
            case 0: System.out.println("File has not mentioned.");  
                    System.exit(0);  
            case 1: System.out.println("Destination file has not mentioned.");  
                    System.exit(0);  
            case 2: copyfile(args[0],args[1]);  
                    System.exit(0);  
            default : System.out.println("Multiple files are not allow.");  
                      System.exit(0);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: ups! thanks @Aniket, although it is still not clear to me what he/she means by call two files :O/

Comment: thanks for your valuable comments but i already use this technique,but i want call two file in using one object

Comment: WTFF (that extra F is indicative of my personal frustration level) do mean by **CALL** a file... You don't (in any accepted sense of any known language, which is a codified, formalised means of expression of ideas) "call a file"... you open them, read and/or write them, and of course you ALLWAYS close them when you're finished with them... you don't CALL Them... so WTTF do YOU mean by "CALL" a file... if your very next utterance doesn't address this question then I'm out... and I feel a few others aren't far behind.